# How do I conditionally format SwiftUI code

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
if(user.reserved == "yes") {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.badge.checkmark").foregroundColor(.green)
            
            Text("\(user.name)").foregroundColor(.green)
        }
    } else if (user.reserved == "no"){
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.badge.checkmark").foregroundColor(.red)
            
            Text("\(user.name)").foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    } else if (user.reserved == "waiting") {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.badge.checkmark").foregroundColor(.orange)
            
            Text("\(user.name)").foregroundColor(.orange)
        }
    }
```

'''

I have this code where I want to change the appearance of the text color based on a user saying yes or no. I tried creating a var like "var color: Color" in the if statements however, it kept saying that it dit not conform to the view. How can I make conditional code effectively instead of having to copy past every thing again and again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a computed property that returns a `Color` based on the user's `reserved` property:

```
struct User {
    var reserved : String
    var name : String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var user = User(reserved: "waiting", name: "Bob")
    
    var colorForReserved : Color {
        switch user.reserved {
        case "yes":
            return .green
        case "no":
            return .red
        case "waiting":
            return .orange
        default:
            return .black
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.badge.checkmark")
            Text(user.name)
        }
        .foregroundColor(colorForReserved)
    }
}
```

*Note that you can avoid the `default` if you changed `reserved` to an `enum` rather than a `String`*

Comment: Thank you so much!! Couldn’t figure out how to get the if statements going.